# HBase reload table data from source - transparent to the user

Tags: hbase

Our current process gets data from source, disables, drops and recreates the HBase table and then loads the new data in the table.

So there is certain amount of time when table is having no data / incomplete data.

Is there a way to reload table data in HBase without this inconsistency?

I was thinking on the lines of creating a stage table with new data and renaming the stage table to main table. This can be done using snapshot feature in HBase but even this requires disable, drop of the existing table, which would still cause this to be "non-transparent"

Comment: This is basically a wrong design. Your application should not drop and recreate HBase table on a recurring basis. Have you checked if HBASE TTL could answer your needs ?

Comment: I know of HBase TTL but can't use it as I need the old data out completely when new data is available. TTL will have fix days of retention specified meaning old data may still be there after new data is available.

Comment: I understand but according to me this is not a correct usage of HBase. Simply use a SQL database for this kind of need